# PHP can't read/receive response

Tags: php, json, steam

So what I am trying to do is receiving data about a player from the Steam API.
Basically, a player logs in via the Steam website and then gets redirected to a page of my website where data about the player is registered into the database. 
It seems that the data about the player (which is being retrieved from the Steam API) is null (it cant be retrieved)

When I try to access the API in the browser, it works just fine.

Here is the code for registering the data:

```
 $url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=". $matches[1];
                $json_object = file_get_contents($url);
                $json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);
                foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player) {
                    $steamid = $player->steamid;
                    $name = $player->personaname;
                    $avatar = $player->avatar;
                }

                $hash = md5($steamid . time() . rand(1, 50));
                $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `steamid` = '" . $steamid . "'");
                $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if (count($row) == 0) {
                    $db->exec("INSERT INTO `users` (`hash`, `steamid`, `name`, `avatar`) VALUES ('" . $hash . "', '" . $steamid . "', " . $db->quote($name) . ", '" . $avatar . "')");
                } else {
                    $db->exec("UPDATE `users` SET `hash` = '" . $hash . "', `name` = " . $db->quote($name) . ", `avatar` = '" . $avatar . "' WHERE `steamid` = '" . $steamid . "'");
                }
```

If you want to try the API out your self, copy the $url and replace $matches[1] with this steam id: 76561198117114460

Thanks in advance,
Guus Huizen

Comment: What are you saying is returning null? Running file_get_contents on that URL works fine for me.

Comment: @JonStirling Could you tell me what it echoes? I will try debugging that statement, hold on.

Comment: What what echoes? The file_get_contents? It echoes exactly what I see when I go to the URL in browser?

Comment: That is very weird, as it did work on my localhost, but now that I am transferring it over to a VPS, it doesnt work anymore. Maybe it is because of the setup on my VPS? I used XAMPP on my localhost.

Comment: The VPS may not have URL file wrappers enabled, you may have to try using cURL instead.

Comment: Off topic: you've exposed the api key, which I assume may be a secret?

Comment: @michaJlS Thank you for letting me know, I completely forgot about that as I am running low on sleep :3

Comment: @JonStirling That would be impossible as I just echoed the url using file_get_contents in a different file and it did echo successfully. Would it have something to do with what I am doing in the file ?

Comment: @GuusHuizen: are you certain of the contents of `$matches[1]` in your code? You refer to that as `$matches[0]` in your description. Should your code actually be using `$matches[0]`. If you supply an empty or invalid `steamid` you will get an empty JSON response. Try printing the URL before calling `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: I will try echoing the $matches[0], but that is basically from a regex which gets the steamid from the url.

Comment: @GuusHuizen: but your code is using `matches[1]`, so you should echo that. Or you should change your code to use `matches[0]` if that is the regex result field that you should be using.

Comment: @JohnStirling echoing $matches[0] gives me a link to their profile. $matches[1] gives me their steamid which is correct. (@mhawke Sorry I meant to say $matches[1] instead of $matches[0])

Comment: @GuusHuizenL that's OK, I just thought that the mismatch might explain it. Can you print the value of `$url` before calling `file_get_contents()`? (remember to obfuscate the key). Is it correct?

Comment: @mhawke this is whats being echoed: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=76561198117114460

Comment: @GuusHuizen: that URL works for me. Can you print the response? Use `var_dump($json_object)`. Is it possible that your IP address has been blocked for making too many requests?